# $U\subseteq V$ is $T$ invartiant $\Rightarrow$ $\left(T\,|_{U}\right)^{*}=\left(P \circ T^{*}\right)\bigl|_{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to proove that given $T\in\mathcal{L}\left(V,V\right)$ ($V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space)  and a subspace $U\subseteq V$ which is $T$ invariant that

$\left(T\,|_{U}\right)^{*}=\left(P\circ T^{*}\right)\bigl|_{U}$

Where $P$ is the projection on $U$.

**My attempt:**
I've tried working with the inner product but  but with no luck because I'm unsure how can I "defuse" all the $^*$. I've all so thought about finding some orthonormal basis of $U$ $\mathcal{B}=\left\{ f_{1},\dots,f_{k}\right\}$ but I didn't know how to express those linear transforms with the basis.

I do understand intuitively why restricting $T^{*}$ is the same as using $T^*$ first and then just projection the result to $U$ but I'm struggling writhing a correct rigorous proof.

I'd be happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to add that you assume $V$ to be a Hilbert space.

Comment: @julien Thanks, but we assumed that $V$ is an inner product space...

Comment: Infinite dimensional? Then you need at least $U$ to be complete for the projection onto $U$ to exist by the standard projection onto complete convex subsets of an inner product space.

Comment: @julien I never said "Infinite dimensional" I've even talked about a basis which implies a finite dimension, but you're still correct I should've mentioned it...

Comment: Also, try do this algebraically: $U$, the range of $P$, is exactly the vectors $v$ such that $Pv=v$. So $U$ is $T$ invariant iff $PTPv=TPv$ for every $v\in V$, i.e. $PTP=TP$. Taking the adjoint of the latter, this is in turn equivalent to $PT^*P=PT^*$, which is actually your condition, if you realize that restricting to $U$ amounts to right-multiply by $P$.

Comment: In finite dimension, an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is automatically complete, whence a Hilbert space... And the property you mention is actually necessary and sufficient, and holds in any Hilbert space for $U$ a closed subspace.

Comment: @julien would you mind explaining the first iff ($U$ is $T$ invariant iff $PTPv=TPv$) ?

Comment: The key point is that for an idempotent operator ($P^2=P$), the range is characterized by $\mbox{Im}\,P=\{v\in V\;;\; Pv=v\}=\mbox{Ker}\,(I-P)$. Once you have that, $U=\mbox{Im}\,P=\{Pv\;;\; v\in V\}$ is $T$ invariant iff $Tw\in \mbox{Im}\,P$ for every $w\in \mbox{Im}\, P$ iff $TPv\in\mbox{Im}\,P$ for every $v\in V$ iff $PTPv=TPv$ for every $v$ iff $PTP=TP$. And the last thing you need is that for a projection $P$ (self-adjoint idempotent), $P^*=P$.

Comment: @julien thanks! Why not write it as answer?

Comment: I don't mind if you write it as an answer yourself if you find this approach useful. I think it would be a great way to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

For $u, v \in U$ we have (denoting by $(,)$ the inner product on $V$ and by $(,)_U$ its restriction to $U$):
\begin{align*}
  (T|_Uu, v)_U &= (Tu, v)\\
               &= (u, T^*v)\\
               &= (u, PT^*v) + (u, (I - P)T^*v)\\
               &= (u, PT^*v)\\
               &= (u, (PT^*)|_Uv)_U
\end{align*}
So $(T|_U)^* = (PT^*)|_U$. In the forth step we used that$\mathrm{ran}(I-P) = U^\bot$ (i. e.  the range of $I-P$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$, as $I-P$ is the projection onto $U^\bot$), hence $(u, (I-P)x) = 0$ for all $x \in V$.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by $ran$? this part was a bit unclear...

Comment: @Scis I edited to explain.